Daisy chain neutral
I want to replace a standard light switch with a smart switch which requires a neutral wire. The box has a neutral bundle with 6 wires already. Can I remove one of the neutrals, connect it with a neutral pigtail off the smart switch, and take another neutral pigtail and connect this new bundle of 3 to the original bundle?
If not, is there anyway other way to add my smart switch ?

You can have two sets of neutrals if there is a jumper between the two sets.
One neutral set of three plus a jumper and one set of three plus the jumper and neutral to the switch. The jumper connects the two sets.
The wire nuts have a specific range of wires they connect together.
The jumper must be the same wire size.  The wire nuts must be rated for the size/number of the wires.
